# Product Scheduling in Package

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, product

I just want to know that can we make product scheduling enable before creating a package because package is not getting installed in the Org until I enable product scheduling manually in the Org. Is there any way while making package we can do something so that the user dont have to enble scheduling manually..
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't force the setting on, because (a) the system checks to make sure it's enabled before your package gets to install, and (b) it is an [unsupported metadata type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm). If (b) were not true, you could use all dynamic bindings to Product Scheduling and use the [InstallHandler Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm). You should include instructions in your setup manual that Product Scheduling must be manually enabled before installing.